# Is there a support for gradientTransform for Android

Tags: android, gradient, radial-gradients

When I import SVG(vector) file using Android Studio the property **gradientTransform** is not imported.

The property allows applying transformations to the gradient, below is an image showing the difference. By using gradientTransform we can change the angle, scale and translation for the radial gradient. I know that Android Studio does not have full SVG support, but is there to mimic the gradientTransform.

[image]

Here is the code for vector file using transform for radial gradient

```xml
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1050" height="245" viewBox="0 0 1050 245">
      <defs>
        <radialGradient id="radial-gradient" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="1.658" gradientTransform="translate(0.383 0.371) scale(0.233 0.259)" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <stop offset="0"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
        </radialGradient>
      </defs>
      <g id="Rectangle_865" data-name="Rectangle 865" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1" fill="url(#radial-gradient)">
        <rect width="1050" height="245" stroke="none"/>
        <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="1049" height="244" fill="none"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```